# How to set width/height in code without breaking Grid star-size?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have some XAML code like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="g1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Pink"/>
        <Grid x:Name="g2" Grid.Row="1" Background="Green"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>

<Button Content="Update Size" Width="150" Height="50" Click="Button_Click" Margin="105,342,0,248"/>
```

and code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    g1.Width = mainGrid.ActualWidth;
    g1.Height = mainGrid.ActualHeight / 2;
}
```

it shows before clicking the button like this:

[image]

after clicking the button and drag the window to a bit larger, it looks like this:

[image]

so my question is, before clicking the button if you drag the window around the star-sizing works and resize both top/bottom grids as window resizes, however after clicking the buttom, which sets g1 width and height, it breaks star-sizing. how do i bring the star-sizing back to work again after set the width and height?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Setting the dimensions of `g1` isn't breaking the star-sizing. It just prevents that element from stretching to fill the grid cell that it's in. The cell itself is still fine, and star-sizing is still causing it to take up the 50% height it's supposed to. What behavior did you expect? Please be _specific_. What exactly did you expect to happen, that's not happening right now?

Comment: @Peter Duniho i expect the stretching works after button is clicked. as you mentioned it prevents from stretching to fill the grid cell that it's in. i am trying to find a way to have the stretching works again after setting its width and height in code.

Comment: _"i am trying to find a way to have the stretching works again after setting its width and height in code"_ -- why do you think that should work? Stretching by definition is a mechanism by which the width and height of the element are automatically determined by the relationship to the container. Setting the width and height by definition is a mechanism to explicitly control the width and height. The two are, by definition, mutually exclusive of each other. Why would you think that when you tell WPF you want a specific width and height, it should do anything except maintain those dimensions?

Comment: @Peter Duniho for example if i had a list view with items longer than g1's current height, when i'm adding it to g1 and creating a 3rd grid called g3 on the 3rd row sharing same star-sizing with g1 and g2 at the same time, the list view will change the height of g1 and cause row definition becomes uneven between g1,g2, and g3. what i am trying to do here is after adding the list view to g1, all 3 grids still keep their original sharing star-size, and when i resize the window all 3 grids still function as stretching to the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do i bring the star-sizing back to work again after set the width and height?

After you set the width and height for Grid `g1`, you broke the auto star-sizing. But you can use the [Window.SizeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.window.sizechanged.aspx) event to monitor the size changing of the application window view instead. When window size changed, dynamically set new height and width for `g1` by yourself to fit the parent control `mainGrid`.

Code like follows will meet you current requirements.

```
 public Strangelaout()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;
 }

 private void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     g1.Width = mainGrid.ActualWidth;
     g1.Height = mainGrid.ActualHeight / 2;
 }

 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     g1.Width = mainGrid.ActualWidth;
     g1.Height = mainGrid.ActualHeight / 2;
 }
```